# Android Studio - empty project after importing from Github

Tags: application-development, android, repository, android-studio, github

I have a big problem with android studio. Now I'm working on a project and I have to pair the repository from github to android studio.

The connection and the clone of the folder went well. I can't display all the files and folders from the tab on the left side [image]

It says "Nothing to show" although I should see the file listing. How can I get it back?

Comment: it seems to be that AS doesn't import your project properly

Comment: delete your project, clone it into the other folder, open Android Studio, then `New -> Import Project` it should ask you about Gradle ;-)

Comment: @piotrek1543 I need to import from github, all the procedure of import went everytime well..the problem is after..

Comment: @piotrek1543 Also if I download the zip of the all repository it give to me the same problem.

Comment: may I see this github repository? I said clone it to directory - do not import it directly form ANdroid Studio - see your imported project is not configured

Comment: @piotrek1543 which directory do you mean?

Comment: for example Desktop. Just clone it to other place and import it using `Import` option, not `form Project form Version Control` or similar

Comment: @piotrek1543 just tryed..I still have the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue, That the Android Project view is empty.

What i did was clicked on the Gradle menu option on the right side in Android Studio and clicked the Refresh button there, after the Android view looks correct.

Comment: It was a problem with iml file check also the workspace.iml and the Android manifest

Answer (score 0):

Go to File -> Close Project, and next select "Import project" not "Open project".

Answer (score 0):

Sync Project with Gradle files.

There is a useful shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, after which a window appears and you can type some text like "sync" in there and it will find that command **Sync Project with Gradle Files**. Just execute the command.